Spectral projections for compact operators
In this Wikipedia page, under section named "Invariant subspaces", it is shown that for a compact operator $C$ on a Banach space $X$, the Riesz projection defined as $E(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma (\xi - C)^{-1} d \xi$ is exactly a projection onto $ker(\lambda - C)^\nu$, where $\nu$ is the smallest integer such that $ker(\lambda -C)^{\nu} = ker(\lambda -C)^{\nu+1}$.
During the proof, it is claimed that

$E(\lambda)(\lambda - C)^\nu = (\lambda -C)^\nu E(\lambda) = 0$
$im(E(\lambda)) = ker(\lambda -C)^{\nu}$ because of the previous claim.

I don't understand how can we derive those two statements. Can anyone explain them a little bit more? Thanks!

Let $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
E(\lambda)(\lambda - C)^\nu = (\lambda -C)^\nu E(\lambda) \tag{1}
$$
follows from
$$
(\lambda -C)^\nu E(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma (\lambda -C)^\nu (\xi - C)^{-1} d \xi =  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma  (\xi - C)^{-1} (\lambda -C)^\nu d \xi = E(\lambda)(\lambda - C)^\nu
$$
together with the fact that $C$ commutes with its resolvent.
If $x \in \ker (\lambda - C)^\nu$, then
\begin{align*}
x - E(\lambda) x = (I - E(\lambda) ) x
&= (\lambda - C)|_{\operatorname{ran}(I - E(\lambda))}^{-\nu} (\lambda - C)^\nu (I - E(\lambda) ) x \\ &= 
(\lambda - C)|_{\operatorname{ran}(I - E(\lambda))}^{-\nu}  (I - E(\lambda) )(\lambda - C)^\nu x = 0
\end{align*}
which shows that $x = E(\lambda ) x $ and hence $\ker (\lambda - C)^\nu \subset \operatorname{ran}(E(\lambda))$.
The fact that $(\lambda - C)|_{\operatorname{ran}(I - E(\lambda))}$ is invertible follows from the spectral mapping theorem and some other properties of the holomorphic functional calculus.
To prove the existence of $\nu$ so that
$$
(\lambda -C)^\nu E(\lambda) =0 
$$
is more tricky, you can find a proof here.
Finally if
$$
(\lambda -C)^\nu E(\lambda) =0 
$$
then obviously $\operatorname{ran}(E(\lambda)) \subset \ker (\lambda -C)^\nu$ and so together with what was shown above
$$
\operatorname{ran}(E(\lambda)) =\ker (\lambda -C)^\nu.
$$
